# R, leaflet, fill polygons with colours

Tags: r, leaflet

I have shape data for London, and want to colour different regions red, yellow, and green.

My code works, but does not fill it according to red, yellow, or green.

The data is: https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london

Here is my code:

```
library("rgdal")
library(leaflet)
shapeData <- readOGR('statistical-gis-boundaries-london/ESRI/LSOA_2004_London_Low_Resolution.shp')
shapeData <- spTransform(shapeData, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80"))
LANAME='Camden'
shapeData$col=sample(c('red','yellow','green'),nrow(shapeData),1)
leaflet()  %>% addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = -0.106, lat=51.5177,zoom=14) %>% 
  addPolygons(data=bor,weight=2,col = 'black',fillOpacity = 0.02,fillColor = shapeData$col,
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color='white',weight=1,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE)) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng = -0.106,lat=51.5177,popup="Hi there")
```

The output is:

[image]

Can anyone point out why I do not see yellow, green, or red only, and see all these other colours as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just happened to have that file downloaded already..

Your problem is that the `data` argument doesn't align with your `fillColor` parameter. Instead you should run:

```
leaflet()  %>% addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = -0.106, lat=51.5177,zoom=14) %>% 
  addPolygons(data=shapeData,weight=2,col = 'black',fillColor = shapeData$col,
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color='white',weight=1,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE)) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng = -0.106,lat=51.5177,popup="Hi there")
```

I also removed the `fillOpacity = 0.02` argument as it was making the colours far too transparent to see.

Comment: bad error on my side. I was playing with subsets on the side, and forgot to change it back. Thanks for the catch!!

Comment: No problem, it happens!